# pySpark - Find common values in grouped data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to find common values among the groups created by applying groupBy and pivot on a dataframe in pySpark.
For example, the data looks like:

```
+--------+---------+---------+
|PlayerID|PitcherID|ThrowHand|
+--------+---------+---------+
|10000598| 10000104|        R|
|10000908| 10000104|        R|
|10000489| 10000104|        R|
|10000734| 10000104|        R|
|10006568| 10000104|        R|
|10000125| 10000895|        L|
|10000133| 10000895|        L|
|10006354| 10000895|        L|
|10000127| 10000895|        L|
|10000121| 10000895|        L|
```

After applying:

```
df.groupBy('PlayerID').pivot('ThrowHand').agg(F.count('ThrowHand')).drop('null').show(10)
```

I get something like:-

```
+--------+----+---+
|PlayerID| L  |  R|
+--------+----+---+
|10000591|  11| 43|
|10000172|  22|101|
|10000989|  05| 19|
|10000454|  05| 17|
|10000723|  11| 33|
|10001989|  11| 38|
|10005243|  20| 60|
|10003366|  11| 26|
|10006058|  02| 09|
+--------+----+---+
```

is there someway I can get common values of 'PitcherID' among the count of L and R in the above.

What i mean is for PlayerID =10000591, I have 11 PitcherID where ThrowHand is L and 43 PitcherID where ThrowHand is 43. It is possible that some Pitchers are common in this 11 and 43 Pitchers grouped.

Is there any way I can get these common PitcherID?

Answer (score 1):

You should first get the collection of *pitcherIds* for each *throwhand* as

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
#collect set of pitchers in addition to count of ThrowHand
df = df.groupBy('PlayerID').pivot('ThrowHand').agg(F.count('ThrowHand').alias('count'), F.collect_set('PitcherID').alias('PitcherID')).drop('null')
```

which should give you `dataframe` as

```
root
 |-- PlayerID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- L_count: long (nullable = false)
 |-- L_PitcherID: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- R_count: long (nullable = false)
 |-- R_PitcherID: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Then write a `udf` function to get the common `pitcherID`s as

```
#columns with pitcherid and count
pitcherColumns = [x for x in df.columns if 'PitcherID' in x]
countColumns = [x for x in df.columns if 'count' in x]

#udf function to find the common pitcher between the collected pitchers
@F.udf(T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
def commonFindingUdf(*pitcherCols):
    common = pitcherCols[0]
    for pitcher in pitcherCols[1:]:
        common = set(common).intersection(pitcher)
    return [x for x in common]

#calling the udf function and selecting the required columns
df.select(F.col('PlayerID'), commonFindingUdf(*[col(x) for x in pitcherColumns]).alias('common_PitcherID'), *countColumns)
```

which should give you final `dataframe` as

```
root
 |-- PlayerID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- common_PitcherID: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- L_count: long (nullable = false)
 |-- R_count: long (nullable = false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful